# Как собрать javaFx проект

Tags: java, javafx, jar

когда достиг финальной части своего задания столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не могу собрать проект в полноценный jar файл, выдаёт ошибку - Error:Java FX Packager: Can't build artifact - fx:deploy is not available in this JDK. Поискав я понял, что это можно сделать с помощью maven и gradle, однако с ними я никогда не пересекался.     Собственно хотел узнать, может кто-нибудь знает способ, как без maven или gradle можно собрать проект?

Comment: Возможно можно средой разработки собрать. Как вы довели проект до финальной стадии ни разу его не собирая? Без отладки?

Comment: артефакт создавайте с манифестом, и будем вам счастье

Answer (score 0):

Из контекста очевидно имеется ввиду, что вы проект собирали, но не в виде конечного jar.

Спешу вас порадовать более-менее любая среда разработки умеет собирать также и jar.

[Документация по сборке jar для Intellij IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/packaging-a-module-into-a-jar-file.html)

Comment: Получается это будет jar, но без поддержки javaFx? Я добавил в своём вопросе строчку "выдаёт ошибку - Error:Java FX Packager: Can't build artifact - fx:deploy is not available in this JDK" эту ошибку выдаёт при Artifacts ->JavaFx Application. Я пробовал и метод присланный вами, но потом при запуске через командную строку у меня вылезают такие ошибки: Error: Could not find or load main class sample.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

Comment: 1) Это значит, что при сборке JAR вы не включили в нее библиотеки JavaFX
2) Вы не указываете `Main` класс - точку входа в приложение.

Вопросы элементарные и решаются обычным гуглением и чтением мануалов.

Comment: 1)Единственное, что я понял гугля эту проблему это то, что в jdk11 больше не поддерживается javaFx. 2)Так при создании же артефакта выбирается Main Class

Comment: 1) Вы не поняли - входит в состав JDK или не входит - это не про это (в вашем случае JavaFX входит в состав JDK, иначе не компилировалось бы). Надо включить либы JavaFX в состав самого JAR.

Comment: Хорошо, но тогда как это сделать?